# How to install packages in Enthought Canopy without X?

Tags: python, enthought

I have been using [Enthought Python Distribution](https://www.enthought.com/products/epd/) (EPD) for some time. It allows the user to install the latest precompiled python packages (e.g. numpy, scipy) with a single command.

Today I wanted to install EPD on a new machine, but found that they've replaced it by a new product called [Enthought Canopy](https://www.enthought.com/products/canopy/). The problem with Canopy is that it has a GUI:

```
__boot__.py: cannot connect to X server
```

My machines are headless and don't run X servers. Is it possible to install packages in Canopy without X? I've searched their knowledge base but couldn't find a solution. They request that unpaid and academic users post questions on Stack Overflow instead of contacting them.

If that's not possible, is there a way to install EPD any more?

Edit: I realize that this question doesn't really belong to SO. Please migrate it to SU if needed. Thanks.

Comment: EPD is a development tool so we think your question belongs on SO even though it is about EPD installation.

Comment: Canopy does provide some headless operation, but as you observed, it is not yet publicly documented, because it is not yet well-tested in multiple environments. Please feel free to email canopy.support@enthought.com for details.

Comment: Thanks, I've emailed them